# What are the parameters for ON_LBN_SELCHANGE?

Tags: c++, mfc

I couldn't find anywhere in MSDN an example of handling ON_LBN_SELCHANGE. So, how does the afx_msg function look like, and what parameters does ON_LBN_SELCHANGE need in the message map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notification handler for `LBN_SELCHANGE` has no parameters.

All listbox notification handlers have a common syntax ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y04ez4c9%28v=vs.80%29.aspx))

> Each message-map entry takes the following form:
>
> ```
>     ON_Notification( id, memberFxn )
> ```
>
> where id specifies the child window ID of the list-box control sending the notification 
>   and memberFxn is the name of the parent
>   member function you have written to handle the notification.
>
> The parent's function prototype is as follows:
>
> ```
>     afx_msg void memberFxn( );
> ```